# How to show the complete number on yaxis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

[image]

On the y-axis, instead of showing the multiplier "x 10^4", how can I show the complete number, like 2000, 1500?

```
figure(1);
plot(grid,f_appr);
set(gca,'FontSize',14);
xlabel('x','fontsize',16);
```

Comment: please show us the `plot` code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TickLabelFormat` property such as [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.numericruler-properties.html). Set this property to `%d` for your question. Also, there are different values for a specific precision or other numeric formats.